# Redirect incoming URL to a specific page on current domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I would like to redirect a specific URL www.test1.com/ab to www.test2.co.uk/ab

Note: I only want the /ab folder to redirect to this URL, all other urls should go to www.test2.co.uk

I've only got access to the FTP of the latter.

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1.com/ab
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test1.com/ab
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.test2.co.uk/ab [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ab(/|$) http://www.test2.co.uk/ab [R=301,L,NC]
```